# how to set existing kinesis stream arn in function event

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless framework and trying to deploy Lambda function with event/trigger definition.
The event source is Kinesis stream that already exist.
I'm trying to set the stream ARN with Fn::Join function, but it seems not supported.
How can I set the event stream ARN without hard coding the AWS region and account Id?

My yml code:

```
functions:
    myfunction:
    handler: myfunction.handler
    name: myfunction-name
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 120
    events:
      - stream:
          type: kinesis
          arn:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:kinesis:"
                - Ref: AWS::Region
                - ":"
                - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                - ":stream/xxxxxxx"
          batchSize: 300
          startingPosition: LATEST
          enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the simplicity and readibility of the sub function over the join.

`!Sub arn:aws:kinesis:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stream/xxxx`

Rereading that it relates to the serverless framework, I'd leverage this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use Fn::GetAtt.

from aws documentation:

**Fn::GetAtt**

returns a value for the Arn attribute.

**Arn**

The Amazon resource name (ARN) of the Kinesis stream, such as arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-2:123456789012:stream/mystream.

For more information about using Fn::GetAtt, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

Comment: Thanks for responding...
Since the Kinesis stream already exist, its definition in included in my yml, so I cant referencing the Fn:GetAtt to any resource. I also tried to set the Kinesis stream as a Resource in my yml, but got an error "the stream already exist". Is there a way to reference a resource already exist?

Comment: you can see how to do it :

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-reference-resource/

Comment: The Kinesis stream already exist, and didnt created by different CF.